# How to programmatically alpha fade a textured object in OpenGL ES 1.1 (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, opengl, fade, textures, alpha

I've been using OpenGL ES 1.1 on the iPhone for 10 months, and in that time there is one seemingly simple task I have been unable to do: programmatically fade a textured object. To keep it simple: how can I alpha fade, under code control, a simple 2D triangle that has a texture (with alpha) applied to it. I would like to fade it in/out while it is over a scene, not a simple colored background. So far the only technique I have to do this is to create a texture with multiple pre-faded copies of the texture on it. (Yuck)

As an example, I am unable to do this using Apple's GLSprite sample code as a starting point. It already textures a quad with a texture that has its own alpha. I would like to fade that object in and out.

Answer (score 15):

Maybe I'm not getting you right, but to me it seems trivial and I've been doing it my apps successfully. The way to go is:

1. enable texturing and everything you need
2. enable blending: `glEnable(GL_BLEND)`
3. select a blend mode `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`
4. set a color to blend with: `glColor4f(r * a, g * a , b * a, a)`
5. draw your geometry

The blend function is for [porter-duff over](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porter-Duff) using premultiplied colors/textures. The `GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE` must be set to `GL_MODULATE`, but that's the default.

Comment: Thanks to some help on the Apple dev forums, I got this working using a different variation, thanks! Also, when I tried using "GL\_ONE" instead of "GL\_SRC\_ALPHA" it would not fade for me.

Comment: That's why I explicitly specified *premultiplied* colors. That's the normal way colors are handled in Quartz bitmap contexts and therefore in textures loaded into GL. If your colors are nonpremultiplied, the blend func you specified works as expected (except for target alpha, but that's usually irrelevant).

Answer (score 2):

Nikolai's solution is correct; please ignore what I said on the Apple forums.  Since the texture is pre-multiplied, the per-vertex color should be too.  You should use **GL_ONE** rather than **GL_SRC_ALPHA**, and do this:

```
glColor4f(1., 1., 1., myDesiredAlpha);
glColor4f(myDesiredAlpha, myDesiredAlpha, myDesiredAlpha, myDesiredAlpha);
```